# How to use google OAuth from mobile, using laptop IP instead of localhost?

Tags: web, mobile, localhost, google-oauth, hosting

I am building a web app which is currently only on localhost on my station. This is supposed to work on mobile as well, so I am also testing it by connecting to my laptop's IP from my phone. This works fine, except for the google OAuth. I get the error that

`google permission denied to generate login hint for target domain`

I am guessing the reason is that the ip is not within the allowed origins/redirects of google OAuth, but there is no way I can use localhost, from what I read, and it seems like I cant add the specific IP either (which makes sense). So do you have any idea if there is any way I could test it on mobile while not hosting it? Thanks in advance!